# How to decrement Auto column or Field by one using UPDATE SET on LibreOffice Base?

Tags: sql, database, field, libreoffice-base, auto-value

I have a table with auto increment column (ID) and have already filled my table with records. Then, after sometime I noticed that the auto increment (ID) column started from 2 instead of 1. I really wanted the count to start from 1. So, what I want to do is decrease the ID column by one for all the records using SQL statement UPDATE SET. I have used this SQL Statement on MySQL database and it worked. However, on LibreOffice base, it won't even allow me to execute Update statement saying that it is NOT a query. So, following is what I want to do.

```
UPDATE Accounts SET ID=ID-1;
```

Apparently, LibreOffice base doesn't like that sql statement. So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you tried to create a query, but that is not how to run an update command.  Instead, go to `Tools -> SQL` and enter the following:

```
UPDATE "Accounts" SET ID=ID-1;
```

This was tested using the default HSQLDB engine.